# First Call to a Controller, Constant is defined, Second call, "uninitialized constant Oauth"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, controllers, uninitialized-constant

I am trying to get the OAuth gem to work with Rails 3 and I'm running into this weird problem... (independent of the gem, I think I've run into this once before)

I have a controller called "OauthTestController", and a model called "ConsumerToken".  The model looks like this.

```
require 'oauth/models/consumers/token'
class ConsumerToken < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Oauth::Models::Consumers::Token
end
```

When I go to "/oauth_test/twitter", it loads the `Oauth::Models::Consumers::Token` module and I'm able to connect to twitter no problem.  But the second time I try it (just refresh the `/oauth_test/twitter` url), it gives me this error:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Oauth):
  app/models/consumer_token.rb:4
  app/models/twitter_token.rb:2
  app/controllers/oauth_test_controller.rb:66:in `load_consumer'
```

Why is that?  It has something to do with load paths or being in development mode maybe?

Comment: Does it work in production mode ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using require_or_load instead of require.  That forces full load each time when in development and can sometimes help with this sort of issue.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah it's something to do with being in development mode. Setting config.cache_classes = true in your development.rb get's it working (but is a pain in the ass)